# How to iterate over pixels in a YUV NV12 buffer from camera and set color in Obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, cvpixelbuffer

I need to iterate over the pixels of a YUV NV12 buffer and set color. I think the conversion for NV12 format should be easy but I can't figure it out. If I could set the top 50x50 pixels at 0,0 to white, I'd be set. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the first 3 bytes (12 bits) * number of pixels to all 0x00 or all 0xFF?
Since you really don't seem to care about the conversion simply overwriting the buffer would suffice. If that works, you can tackle the other problems, like finding the right color and producing a rect instead of a line.

For the first, you need to understand the YUV coding. https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV#NV12. According to this document you will most likely need to overwrite bits in the Y range and in the UV range. So writing at two different locations. Thats very contrary to the RGB buffer where all pixel colors have close locality. So you can start and overwrite the first 8 bits in the Y range and the first or last 2 bits in the UV range. That should set you one pixel to a different color than before.

Finally you can tackle the display of the 50x50 rectangle. You'll need to know the image dimensions, because you'll need to offset after each row (if the buffer is transmitted by rows!). E.g., this graph:

```
.------.
|xx    |
|xx    |
|      |
'------'
```

In a rgb color space, with row major transmitted values, the buffer would look like this: `xx0000xx0000000000`. So you would need to overwrite bytes 0-6 and bytes 18-24 (RGB). Because: first range * 3 bytes RGB. Then next range starts at row number (1) * image width (6) * 3 bytes (RGB), and so on. You have to apply the same thinking to the YUV color space.

Comment: Thanks, this clarified things for me. I have a working solution. Not perfect because my math is off, but good enough for what i need.

Comment: Ideally I need to get a clean 50x50 box. I updated the post to reflect what I have so far. it's drawing on the screen but a small sliver of a rectangle, not a clean square. Any ideas?